# Quarkus warning about reflection of BigDecimal

Tags: quarkus

Quarkus is displaying this warning during startup:

```
2020-05-07 10:24:21,302 WARN  [io.qua.dep.ste.ReflectiveHierarchyStep] (build-13) Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
    - java.math.BigDecimal
```

To reproduce, just create a new Quarkus project with only the two classes below.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Product {

    private int id;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public int getId () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice () {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice (BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

```
@Path("Products CRUD")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProductsResource {

    @GET
    public Product get () {
        return new Product();
    }
}
```

The warning appears in version 1.4.2.Final. In version version 1.4.1.Final it does not. Did Quarkus change anything or this is a regression issue?

Comment: Using version 1.4.2.Final btw.

Comment: Just checked, it doesn't happen on version 1.4.1.Final

Comment: Can you add a code snippet on how you are using BigDecimal?

Comment: @PieterjanDeconinck I added it.

Comment: I am also see this for io.quarkus.panache.common.Page in 1.4.2 when I use Panache with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with this specific version of Quarkus.

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/9190 fixes it.